# Ambrosetti-Rabinowitz Condition

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $f(t)=|t|^{\beta-2}t e^{|t|^\frac{N}{N-1}}$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$. We define,
$F(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f(s)\,ds$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$. Here $\beta>q$ for some $q>0$.

I want to check the Ambrosetti-Rabinowitz condition for the function $F$, i.e. if there exist some $\theta>q$ such that
$$
0<\theta F(t)<f(t)t
$$
for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

I tried to use the integration by parts formulae, but unable to get the required inequality. Can somebody please help? Thanks.

Comment: The $s$ in the integral is confusing. What is it supposed to represent? And shouldn't $F = F(t,s)$ then?

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question now. Hope it would be fine.

Comment: Hi, I have tried in the following way: We have $$F(t)=\int_{0}^{t}|s|^{\beta-2}s e^{|s|^\frac{N}{N-1}}\,ds\leq e^{|t|^\frac{N}{N-1}}\int_{0}^{t}|s|^{\beta-1}\,ds=e^{|t|^\frac{N}{N-1}}\frac{|t|^{\beta}}{\beta}=\frac{f(t)t}{\beta},$$ where we have used $|s|\leq t$ inside the integral. Now, since $\beta>q$, the estimate follows. Please inform is you think the argument is fine. Thanks.